# show only Date in auto generated grid view WPF C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I am working on WPF where I use auto generated grid view... date time that stored in a SQL Server 2014 database is in format `2015-08-30` but when it shows on auto generated it shows up as `2015-08-30 12:00:00 AM`

I want to display it as `2015-08-30` only

```
string ConString = // my Connection string
string CmdString = string.Empty;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{
    CmdString = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Client_Info_Detail]";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Client");
    sda.Fill(dt);

    grdClient.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

Comment: Where is the part where you are reading or writing a `DateTime`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and find this code-behind working:
You have to set this event for your datagrid:

```
private void yourDatagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))//if a column is typeof DateTime
    {
        (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";//set your date format 
    }
}
```

This will format any Date column in your datagrid in the format.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the date formatting directly in your XAML with help of the [StringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `Binding` (`System.Windows.Data.Binding`):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd'}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
<dgv:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding YourDate, StringFormat=\{0:yyyy-mm-dd\}}" />
```